# Настройка proxy сервера для VPS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, облако

У меня есть приложение (Nodejs+Nightmarejs+Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS), которое находится на облачном сервере.

Для меня проблема: это запускать приложение через разные прокси сервера. 

Для этого я через **require js** делаю парсинг страниц ( апример http://hideme.ru/proxy-list/), добываю эти ip-адреса, запускаю свое приложение, но в зависимости от качества прокси сервера оно работает (очень редко) либо вообще не запускается.

А если например настроить squid Linux машине оно заработает? Или мне просто не париться и арендовать место на **digitalocean** с поддержкой **proxy**? Хочу знать ваше мнение как мне дальше быть?